# Regular Expression Guidance needed for Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In the following input string:

```
{$foo}foo bar \\{$blah1}oh{$blah2} even more{$blah3} but not{$blarg}{$why_not_me}
```

I am trying to match all instances of `{$SOMETHING_HERE}` that are not preceded by an unescaped backslash.

**Example:**

I want it to match `{$SOMETHING}` but not `\{$SOMETHING}`.

But I do want it to match `\\{$SOMETHING}`

**Attempts:**

All of my attempts so far will match what I want except for tags right next to each other like `{$SOMETHING}{$SOMETHING_ELSE}`

Here is what I currently have:

```
var input = '{$foo}foo bar \\{$blah1}oh{$blah2} even more{$blah3} but not{$blarg}{$why_not_me}';
var results = input.match(/(?:[^\\]|^)\{\$[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\}/g);
console.log(results);
```

Which outputs:

```
["{$foo}", "h{$blah2}", "e{$blah3}", "t{$blarg}"]
```

**Goal**

I want it to be :

```
["{$foo}", "{$blah2}", "{$blah3}", "{$blarg}", "{$why_not_me}"]
```

**Question**

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you need a lookbehind, which JavaScript Regexs don't support

basically you need "${whatever} if it is preceded by a double slash but not a single slash" which is what the lookbehind does.

You can mimic simple cases of lookbehinds, but not sure if it will help in this example. Give it a go: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

**edit**
Btw, I don't think you can do this a 'stupid way' either because if you have `[^\\]\{` you'll match any character that is not a backslash before the brace. You really need the lookbehind to do this cleanly.

Otherwise you can do

```
(\\*{\$[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\})
```

Then just count the number of backslashes in the resulting tokens.

Comment: I am aware a look-behind is what I need and that javascript doesn't support them.I have never done a fake lookbehind before but I will check out the link!

Comment: Thanks for the article! Just what I needed! I posted my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When all else fails, split, join/replace the crap out of it.

Note: the first split/join is actually the cleanup portion. That kills \{<*>}

Also, I didn't account for the stuff inside the brackets since there's code for that already.

```
var input = '{$foo}foo bar \\{$blah1}oh{$blah2} even more\\\\{$blah3} but not{$blarg}{$why_not_me}';

input.split(/(?:[^\\])\\\{[^\}]*\}/).join('').replace(/\}[^\{]*\{/g,'},{').split(/,/));
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what I want:

```
var input = '{$foo}foo bar \\{$blah1}oh{$blah2} even more\\\\{$blah3} but not{$blarg}{$why_not_me}';

var results = [];
input.replace(/(\\*)\{\$[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*\}/g, function($0,$1){
    $0 = $0.replace(/^\\\\/g,'');
    var result = ($0.indexOf('\\') === 0 ? false : $0); 

    if(result) {
        results.push(result);
    }
})

console.log(results);
```

Which gives:

```
["{$foo}", "{$blah2}", "{$blah3}", "{$blarg}", "{$why_not_me}"]
```